# How to migrate a VPS without having to configure again?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, vps, migration

Hello I have an Ubuntu VPS on Vultr configured perfectly for what I need. It has Nginx, Maria DB, PHP and etc. I would like to migrate her to another company. How can I do this migration without having to install and configure everything again on the new VPS?

Comment: you have 2 options either beg your hoster for an backup or do it on your own

Comment: Vultr have a data portability guide at https://www.vultr.com/docs/vultr-data-portability-guide

Answer (score 0):

Write automation scripts to install and configure from a blank OS install. As little user interaction as possible.

Backups are still useful for such a migration. For the data, but also for the OS and everything else, in case something was missed in the migration. As this is to a different provider, take your own backups. For example, tar archives based on LVM snapshots.

---

Some extra work now will give the organization options in the future. Scripted new instance deploy and backup restore will make the next provider or platform migration much easier.

Answer (score 0):

To get an image of your disk at Vultr, you can follow their [guide to boot a rescue OS](https://www.vultr.com/docs/using-finnix-rescue-cd-to-rescue-repair-or-backup-your-linux-system), then copy the disk via SSH to the other host as described in [this Unix StackExchange post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/132797/how-to-dd-a-remote-disk-using-ssh-on-local-machine-and-save-to-a-local-disk). Whether or not that image will boot on your new host depends on the particulars of their setup, but this would also be the most foolproof form of backup you can have should the image not be directly bootable.

While there's a chance this process could lead to a quick and easy migration, it's very possible it wouldn't work at all in which case John's is ultimately the correct answer.